# Change content and foreground color in a label

Tags: vb.net, mvvm, binding

I have this label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding MsgStatus}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Margin="4" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{Binding Color}" />
```

When I click on a button, this label must change, color and content. 
Why this code doesn't work ?

I don't see the content "Wait 20 seconds ...!!" but "Server not found ..! " or "Server connect !! "

```
        Color = "Green"
        MsgStatus = "Wait 20 seconds ...!!"

        Thread.Sleep(500) 'I try this but doesn't work

        Dim oTest As New TestConnect
        Dim sConn As String = "Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=UserDb;Password=Password01"
        If oTest.VerifyConnectionServer(sConn) = False Then
            Color = "Red"
            MsgStatus = "Server not found ..! "
            Status = True
        Else
            Dim Test As Boolean = oTest.SaveNewSQLServerName(NomeServer)
            Color = "Green"
            MsgStatus = "Server connect !! "
            Status = True
        End If
```

Comment: Did you add a name to reference the label?

Comment: if you put a break point on thread.Sleep, what do you see in the label?

Comment: Solved...  I have changed    **'Thread.Sleep(500)** With          **System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()**